# Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handler has been created

Tags: c#, winforms

Within my program, I have two forms, `formLogin` and `formStudent`. The `formLogin` has a connection to a server, through an external class called `Connection`. I am attempting to pass the connection to `formStudent`, show the `formStudent` and hide the `formLogin`. The `Connection` class has two constructors for the forms so that I'm not creating new instances of the forms everywhere and it inherits Form.

The method I am attempting to call from the `Connection` class gives me the error shown in the comment:

```
public void SuccessfulLogin()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => SuccessfulLogin()));
        /*
        **Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window 
        handler has been created**
        */
    }
    else
    {
        formStudent.connection = formLogin.newConnection;
        formLogin.Hide();
        formStudent.Show();
    }
}
```

I have attempted adding `if` statements to see if the handle is created through `if (IsHandleCreated)`, but through using break points it doesn't appear that any of the code in the method is being run at all. I have also tried placing this method in both the `formLogin` class and the `Connection` class, with no changes.

#### UPDATE:

Thank you very much to [King King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679602/king-king), for pointing me in the right direction. I changed my code to this:

```
this.CreateHandle();
this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(SuccessfulLogin));
```

and the `sucessfulLogin` method to this:

```
public void SuccessfulLogin()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => SuccessfulLogin()));
    }
    else
    {
        formStudent = new frmStudent();
        formStudent.connection = formLogin.newConnection;
        formLogin.Hide();
        formStudent.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "Connection" class is a Control too?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - no, but it was the only way I could get past the original error of it not recognizing Invoke at all.

Comment: @KingKing - yes, it is. My apologies for not stating it.

Comment: Please post the main parts of Connection to clear this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `CreateControl()` before calling to `SuccessfulLogin()`:

```
 this.CreateControl();
 this.SuccessfulLogin();
```

Other solutions:

- Call it in a `Load` event handler
- Call it in a `Shown` event handler
- Call it in a `HandleCreated` event handler (Of course, this should be done with some flag to make it work as expected, because the `Handle` may be re-created at runtime at some unpredicted point of time and hence may make the `SuccessfulLogin` called multitime).

Comment: Will I still need to use 
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(SuccessfulLogin));?

Comment: @LaCookie420 yes, just to be sure the `CreateControl` is called before